# Why does gitlab CI does not find my junit report artifact?

Tags: junit, continuous-integration, gitlab, cypress

I am trying to upload J-unit reports on Gitlab CI(these are test results from my Cypress automation framework). I am using Junit-merge. Due the architecture of Cypress (each test in isolation), it requires an extra 'merge' for the reports to get them into one file. Locally evertything works fine:

- Junit generates single reports of each test with a hashcode
- After all reports have been generated I run a script (shown below) that mixed all the reports into one single .xml file and outputs it below the 'results' package.

Tried to debug it locally, but locally everything just works fine. Possiblities I could think of: Either the merge script is not handled properly or Gitlab does not accept the relative path to the .xml file.

```
{
  "baseUrl": "https://www-acc.anwb.nl/",

  "reporter": "mocha-junit-reporter",

  "reporterOptions": {

    "mochaFile": "results/resultsreport.[hash].xml",

    "testsuiteTitle": "true"
  }
}
```

- This is the Cypress.json file, where I configured the Junit reporter and let it output the single testfiles in the results package.

cypress-e2e:

```
image: cypress/base:10

stage: test

script:

- npm run cy:run:staging

- npx junit-merge -d results -o results/results.xml

artifacts:

 paths:

 - results/results.xml

 reports:

  junit: results/results.xml

 expire_in: 1 week
```

- This is part of the yml file. The npx junit-merge command makes sure all .xml files in the results package are being merged into results.xml.

Again, locally everything works as expected. The error I get from gitlab Ci is:

```
Uploading artifacts...
WARNING: results/results.xml: no matching files    
ERROR: No files to upload                          
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Artifacts can only exist in
directories relative to the build directory and specifying paths which don't
comply to this rule trigger an unintuitive and illogical error message (an
enhancement is discussed at
gitlab-ce#15530
). Artifacts need to be uploaded to the GitLab instance (not only the GitLab
runner) before the next stage job(s) can start, so you need to evaluate
carefully whether your bandwidth allows you to profit from parallelization
with stages and shared artifacts before investing time in changes to the
setup.
```

https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ee/tree/master/doc/ci/caching

which means next configuration should fix the problem:

```
artifacts:

 reports:

  junit: <testing-repo>/results/results.xml

 expire_in: 1 week
```